# insert data in two class(table) in Entity Framwork by rerlation many to many

Tags: model-view-controller, entity-framework-4

i create two class in my model and create relation many to many by Entity
in sql my classes is created tables Properly

when i try to insert data in this table get show error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." my cod is:

```
public class News
{

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public virtual Picture Picture { get; set; }
    public virtual NewsType NewsType { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Tag> Tag { get; set; }
    public News(int id, string title, string content, DateTime date)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Title = title;
        this.Content = content;
        this.Date = date;
    }
    public News()
    {

    }
  }
    public class Tag
    {
      public int ID { get; set; }
      public string Title { get; set; }
      public ICollection<News> News { get; set; }

      public Tag()
      {

      }

     }

public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext()
        : base("News")
    {
    }
    static DatabaseContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DatabaseContext>());
    }
    public DbSet<News> newsInfo { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Picture> pictures { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NewsType> Types { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

}
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddNews(NewsViewModel newsInfo)
    {
        using (Models.DatabaseContext dbContext = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            ViewData["Type"] = new SelectList(dbContext.Types.ToList(), "Id", "Title");
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            Models.DatabaseContext dbContext = new Models.DatabaseContext();
            Models.News news = new Models.News();
            news.Title = newsInfo.Title;
            news.Content = newsInfo.Content;
            news.Date = DateTime.Now;
            string newsinput = newsInfo.Tag.cleanTag();
            string[] tags = new string[] { };
            if (newsinput != null)
            {
                tags = newsinput.Split(',');
            }
            foreach (string item in tags)
            {
                Tag findTag = dbContext.Tags.Where(x => x.Title == item).FirstOrDefault();
                if (findTag != null)
                {
                    news.Tag.Add(findTag)
                    ////////////////////////show error in this line
                }
            }

            news.NewsType = dbContext.Types.Find(Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["rdb"]));
            dbContext.newsInfo.Add(news);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Why is `Tag` a nested class?

Comment: It Is Typing mistake

Comment: Well, this it's easy to see what's null in the debugger.

Comment: i find problem:
add ctor in news class and tag class
public News()
        {
            Tags = new List<Tag>();
        }
public Tag()
        {
            News = new List<News>();
        }